# Prevent table from expanding beyond parent

Tags: html, css, overflow, html-table

I have a table that is contained in a parent div.  The issue I'm seeing is that when the table contains data that is larger than the parent, it will expand past the parent.

Here's a fiddle, basically everything needs to be contained in the blue box. (more information below)
http://jsfiddle.net/CjX2v/7/

```
table {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
table > tbody > tr:first-child {
    background-color: green;
    height: 20px;
}
div {
    background-color: blue;
    width:500px;  /* This value is not known, supplied by user */
    height: 500px;  /* This value is not known, supplied by user */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

overflow:hidden will not work as there is text contained in the table that needs to be visible.

I figure it's a pretty straightforward issue, but if you need more information, let me know.

Comment: If there is no particular reason, please avoid using inline styles. especially mixing style rules and inline styles. it makes your code unreadable and hard to work with - [Why use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS). BTW can you explain why the container div is fixed positioned..?

Comment: Don't set a height on the DIV. The table will need some room to expand if it is larger than the parent.

Comment: also, are you aware the the selector `div` applies the css rules to  all `<div>s in your page ..? it looks like you've no idea what you're doing. if not, please explain why you're using such properties and rules...

Comment: @TilwinJoy Sorry about the ugly CSS.  Contrary to what that looks like, I do know what I'm doing :D.  I've updated the link with a more "appropriate" version that should be more readable.

Comment: @TilwinJoy Also, the fixed position is just how we have the div implemented so we can position the content where we want it.  You can remove it, I don't think it's relevant to my problem.

Comment: So do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/CjX2v/8/)?

Comment: @TilwinJoy No, I guess it's easier if I explain the use.  This is specifically for a modal window, where the blue box is the container.  Our users can then say "I want a 200x200 px modal here" and it will show up there with the contained content being scrollable.

Comment: Why are you using tables and positioning? is any of that necessary or do you just need to have one parent div that contains two children? When children are larger than parent the parent div has X and Y scroll?

Comment: @NichoDiaz I'm using the table because I need the content to fill vertically.  Without a table, it's impossible to have two containers, one specified at 20px and the other "the rest".

Answer (score 1):

OK I think this is what you're trying to do.

[Click here for the example: JS FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPkUM/95/)

In order to get the children scrollable in the parent you have to set the overflow of the fixed element.

```
  overflow: auto;
```

In my example `<div class="main">` is the parent and fixed element so the css looks like this.

```
 .main {
    background: black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 40px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.child1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
}

p {
    float: right;
}

.child2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```